# numpy.linalg.inv() doesn't work

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda

I am trying to invert a 2-D matrix using the numpy.linalg.inv() function. However whenever I run it, it just seems to stop. Since I was using a matrix of dimensions 40989x52, I initially thought that this was an issue due to the so I tried waiting for it to process, but it just didn't proceed even after 30+mins. I later tried calling the inv() function with a 3x2 matrix but it surprisingly didn't work either.

I am using python3.6 with Anaconda libraries on 64-bit Ubuntu.

Could this be a library issue or is it an issue with my system?

Comment: `inv` calculates multiplicative inverse, not a pseudoinverse, thus you need a square matrix on input

Comment: But it worked on a different system that I temporarily borrowed from a friend. That system was running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a matrix has more rows than columns (the system of equations has more equations than unknowns), the system could be overdetermined- in other words, there is no exact solution. In fact, you cannot take an inverse of a non-square matrix.

You might want to check the [rank of the matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_rank.html).

However, practically, we end up using the pseudo-inverse for this scenario. You can look into using `pinv`.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html